# Instrumental variable totally changed the endogenous variables's coefficient

Tags: r, instrumental-variables, plm

I have a set of panel data and I am adding one instrumental variable to the panel regression.

The coefficient for the endogenous variable is -3.8% (p<0.0001) with R² =20% but after adding the IV it suddenly changed to +76% (p<0.0001) with R²=-1.2%. I did the following test:

```
summary(iv2,vcov=sandwich,diagnostics=TRUE)
```

And the diagnostic test shows:

*Weak instruments* p-value is 1.45e-11, which means it's not weak
*Wu-Hausman* p-value is <2e-16 , which means IV is consistent and OLS is not

Can anyone please suggest anything? Happy to provide my data.

Comment: *If* your instrumental variable is valid, then you are in the happy situation where you can say "A simple regression of Y on X yielded a negative effect, but, actually, increasing X causes Y to increase as the instrumental variable regression shows!". All that's left to do explain why the correlation is negative in the regression, but positive with IV. For that, you need to think about the causal model that connects Y, X and Z, which you should do anyways to argue that your IV is valid in the first place. We can only help with that if you say what each variable is.

Comment: Rather than providing your data, it would be more helpful if you provided your model. My suspicion is that your IV explains only a narrow portion of the variation in your "endogenous" variable, hence the difference in sign and magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

An instrument has to satisfy two criteria:

***Relevance*** - The instrument and the instrumented variable are sufficiently correlated; that is what you test with the weak dependence test

***Exogeneity*** - The instrument is not correlated with the error of the regression, where you are instrumenting.

As you have only one instrument you ***cannot test exogeneity*** and have to think whether it is reasonable to ***assume exogeneity*** based on the information about the data set.

If the instrument is exogenous and the Hausman-Wu test rejects the null hypothesis, this tells you that the estimates of the consistent estimator (IV) and the efficient estimator (OLS) differ (which is waht you see in your regression output). Thus you should use the IV estimate.

If however the instrument is not exogenous the assumptions of the  Hausman-Wu test are ***violated*** and the result of the test is not informative. In this case both regressions (IV and OLS) are inconsistent.

Comment: thxs Grada, but i don't think you answered my question so what does change of coefficient and p value by adding IV.